# Converting TensorShape([1, 600, 1200, 3]) to png

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing

My model is outputting an image of size: `TensorShape([1, 600, 1200, 3])`

I'm attempting to output this image like this:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(np.asarray(tensor_image)).show()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1200, 3), <f4
```

I'm not sure how I should resize the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging tensorflows exporting functions worked:

tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img('file.png',tensor_image[0])

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to show a batch of images(in this case one image in bath)
use the first output as bellow:

```py
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(np.asarray(tensor_image[0])).show()
```